# Please help improve my proof that Then $S=A^{\top} A$ is positive definite if and only if $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\{\overrightarrow{0}\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I've been asked (I think*) to write a proof for the following theorem:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
Then $S=A^{\top} A$ is positive definite if and only if $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\{\overrightarrow{0}\}$.

Using this definition of p.d.(by me) as:
Let $S \in R^{n \times n}$
then $S$ is said to be positive definite if $x^{\top} S x>0$ for all non-zero vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

I didn't have a lot of time, and I had to infer the theorem and proof from some notes.
Personally I would prove this with the eigenvalues which is much more intuitive (in my opinion) but this is what I'm working with:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \neq 0$.
Notice that we can rewrite the quadratic form $x^{\top} A^{\top} A x$ as the dot product of the vector $ y = Ax $ with itself. Then we can see that,
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{\top} A^{\top} A x &=(A x)^{\top}(A x) \\
&=(y)^{\top}(y)\\
&=\|y\|_{2}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
results in nothing but the length $y$.

$\Longrightarrow$
The length of a vector $y=A x$ is positive provided $y \neq 0$, it follows that if $Ax = 0$ when $x \neq 0$ then $\operatorname{Ker}(A) \neq \{\overrightarrow{0}\}$.

$\Longleftarrow$ Assume that $\operatorname{ker}(A) \neq\{0\}$ then there exists some vector $x$ s.t. $A x=0$ and therefore $(A x)^{\top}(A x)=0^{\top} 0=0$ which is not strictly greater than 0.

It is to help students like me and thus I would like to make it as intuitive as possible (which is why I'll likely also add the eigenvalue proof), I feel like it can be much better.

Thank you so much for any tips that'll help me improve, general suggestions are welcome too, I'll likely have to write a lot of these soon.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to get rid of the $y = Ax$ and just use $Ax$, I think this would simplify things a lot and improve clarity. But the y was in the notes I'm supposed to base this on, so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Your proof is correct! While you might find the eigenvalue approach more intuitive, this approach has the benefit of being very self-contained. For example, I suspect that any proof of this statement that uses eigenvalues would have to rely on the spectral theorem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much! I was thinking whether I should have to prove the eigenvalue property itself. Professor asked me to be rigorous. At the same time it's notes for students by students so thinks imho should be intuitive.

Also, first time I wrote anything like this, so I'm super happy for your feedback, gives me a lot of confidence going forward.

Comment: I would suggest that the $x^TSx > 0$ definition is an important one to get a "feeling" for, since it is a much more efficient lens for many statements about positive definite matrices. For example, one important statement is that for positive (semi-)definte matrices $A,B$, the sum $A + B$ will also be positive (semi-)definite. This statement is (in my opinion) opaque from the perspective of eigenvalues (how exactly should the eigenvalues of $A+B$ relate to the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $B$?) but (relatively) obvious if we use the other definition.

Comment: This perspective is also particularly important in operator theory (infinite dimensional linear algebra) because the "eigenvalues" in that context become much trickier to work with.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you! that's a nice property to add as well, I'll keep it in my notes and make a suggestion to augment it too. It would indeed be difficult to show this with the eigenvalues (I don't think I could but may try).
I'd like to add I'm having so much fun, this is difficult but I learn a lot thinking about math this way.